# List of items in Selenium WebDriver using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to write the same piece of code in C# ?

```
List<WebElement> displayedOptions = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("select"));
for (WebElement option : displayedOptions) 
 {
    if (option.displayed) 
    {
        displayedOptions.Add(option);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a class created specifically for `select` HTML elements (i.e. dropdowns).

It is the [SelectElement](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver.Support/UI/SelectElement.cs) class inside the **OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI** namespace.

This is a wrapper around `select` elements, giving easy access to common things people use/interact with in `select` elements.

Your example would be translated into (using C# 3 or above, since I'm using LINQ):

```
IList<IWebElement> selectElements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("select"));
var displayedSelectElements = selectElements.Where(se => se.Displayed);
```

It's important to know what this code does. It will first find *all* `select` elements and put them into a new list.

It will then filter those out, to only the `select` elements that are displayed, that is, their `.Displayed` property is **true**. This is a direct translation of your example code.

However, you've not really specified what you are trying to do, and I think the example is better suited as this:

```
var selectElement = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("something")));
var displayedOptions = selectElement.Options.Where(o => o.Displayed);
```

The above would find a *specific* `select` elements, and filter the options *within* that `select` to only those that are displayed. Again, that is, have their `.Displayed` property as **true**.

**Edit**

Since the above code is what you need, but you want in the form of a `for` loop, a similar thing would look like:

```
var selectElement = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("something")));
var allOptions = selectElement.Options;

for (int i = 0; i < allOptions.Length; i++)
{
    if (allOptions[i].Displayed)
    {
        // do something
        // like add to a new list?
    }
}
```

Comment: But can i use the same format of for in C# instead of foreach ?

Comment: @jessica, absolutely, have edited my post to show that - let me know if it still isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

FindElements returns ReadOnlyCollection. So its better to define

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> displayedOptions  = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("select"));

for (WebElement option : displayedOptions) 
{
  if (option.displayed) 
  {
    //displayedOptions.Add(option); //You can't do that
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SVG data looks like this :

```
<div id="content-data" class="col-md-12" style="height:666px;">
  <svg id="pie-draw-488172" width="492" height="616"><g transform="translate(226,318)">
    <text id="pie-text" cursor="default" y="-226" x="241">Compute (227,311)</text> 
    <text id="pie-text" cursor="default" y="-211" x="241">Database (98,005)</text>
    <text id="pie-text" cursor="default" y="-196" x="241">Storage&amp;Content Delivery (69,436)</text>
    <text id="pie-text" cursor="default" y="-181" x="241">Networking (30,874)</text>
    <text id="pie-text" cursor="default" y="-166" x="241">Other (11,273)</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

then use this

```
public List<IWebElement> content_data = new List<IWebElement>();  
content_data = driver.FindElement(By.Id("content-data")).FindElements(By.TagName("text")).ToList();
```